# URLs aliases with different cultures and language variables - base URL doesn't lock to culture

Tags: url, culture

So I have set up URL aliases that are set to each culture.

/english
/french

There is also a language toggle that uses these variables:
?lang=en-ca
?lang=fr-ca

Is there a way to get the language toggle to change the alias of the page to the right one without just displaying "/english?lang=fr-ca"? And I have noticed that once the French variable has been used the /english alias goes to the French page, even without the variable. This doesn't happen with /french though (this always directs to the right one). I guess this is because /english is the default location when the page was created.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by setting "Use name path for URL path" and not using custom paths.

But is there a way to use a variable or macro to switch cultures in this mode to show a specific culture version of the current page. The variable I mentioned before doesn't work now, it stays on the current language regardless when at:

So I have set up URL aliases that are set to each culture.

/english?lang=fr-ca OR /english?lang=en-ca

Ideally, I would like to redirect to /french when the 1st one is used.